# Where should I synchronize on this static SharedPreference helper class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, synchronized

I have created a class holding SharedPreferences access in a static manner. Looking at the AOSP ContextImpl.java's SharedPreferenceImpl, I see that `synchronized(this)` is used when `put` and `get` are executed.

Should I still add `synchronized` somewhere in my code below?

```
public class AppPreferences {
  // Get static SharedPreferences Editor
  private static Editor getEditor(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
  }
  // Get static SharedPreferences
  private static SharedPreferences getPref(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
  }
  public static String getUserName(Context ctx, String defaul) {
    return getPref(ctx).getString("user_name", defaul);
  }
  public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String text) {
    getEditor(ctx).putString("user_name", text).commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?

Comment: I still dont know the correct answer

Comment: See also here : https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpers/blob/master/src/gr/uoa/di/android/helpers/AccessPreferences.java for my attempt at a prefs wrapper - and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610569/android-sharedpreferences-null-keys-values-and-sets-corner-cases for some fine points

Answer (score 0):

In `android.app.ContextImpl` there is a [static field](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.0sSharedPrefs)

```
private static final HashMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl> sSharedPrefs =
         new HashMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl>();
```

(aside `private static final HashMap` ?! /aside).
This is populated [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#346). So all threads in an application sharing the same context (I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327221/getdefaultsharedpreferences-what-is-the-context-for-a-multi-package-applicat) but I am still not quite 100% certain) will share this static map of `SharedPreferencesImpl` instances - Now whenever you call edit() you get a [new EditorImpl instance](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#2837) - so in the "synchronized(this)" you refer to in your question the *this* refers to the instance of EditorImpl at hand - which does not do much - it just synchronizes access to the internal map of the EditorImpl. But the (different) editors synchronize on the (*common*) *SharedPreferencesImpl* instance when they are about to modify this (SharedPreferencesImpl) instance. So in `commit()` for instance `commitToMemory()` is [called](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#2999) where the synchronization [is on](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#2937) `SharedPreferencesImpl.this`. Keep in mind though that the writes to disk are enqueued in random order (see the javadoc for  [enqueueDiskWriteSo](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#3052) and notice in `commit` that no lock is held between writing to memory and enqueing for write to disk). So you should be safe modifying the preferences as long as you do not depend on order of modifications and do not depend on *atomically* checking *and* setting a preference value (which needs synchronizing of your own)
NB the code I quote is for 2.3.1_r1 - hopefully still valid